# Can't get JavaScript navigation bar to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is happening is nothing at all. I scroll down and the bar stays the same size. I scroll back up nothing happens either. Putting the code into three separate files as they are below is not working like the JFiddle is.

Basically, I have been trying to implement this fiddle but for some reason, I can see it working on the website but it does not work on my version.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JJ8Jc/258/

Maybe I am linking JavaScript incorrectly or something.

I'm using Google Chrome.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Nav</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="nav.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header_nav">
    <div id="header_div">
        div
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
height:2000px;
width:100%;
background-color:#F0F0F0;
}

#header_nav {
width:100%;
height:100px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-left:10px;
background-color:#fff;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
text-align:center;
border-bottom:1px solid #c1c1c1;
}

#header_div
{
position:relative;
background-color:#14a;
color:#c1c1c1;
height:30px;
width:40px;
display:inline-block;
padding-top: 10px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
    $(function(){
$('#header_nav').data('size','big');
$('#header_div').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
{
    if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'big')
    {
        $('#header_nav').data('size','small');
        $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
            height:'40px'
        },600);
        $('#header_div').data('size','small');
        $('#header_div').stop().animate({
            height:'20px',
            width: '20px',
            'padding-top' : 5
        },600);
    }
}
else
{
    if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'small')
    {
        $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
        $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
            height:'100px'
        },600);
        $('#header_div').data('size','big');
        $('#header_div').stop().animate({
            height:'30px',
            width: '40px',
            'padding-top' : 10
        },600);
    }  
}
});
```

Comment: i cannot see where did you included jquery?? it won't work without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your html into this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Nav</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="nav.js"></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'><script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header_nav">
    <div id="header_div">
        div
    </div>
</div>
```

You might want to check the line that I added:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'><script>
```

As I memorised it so am not sure it is right

Comment: This did it! What exactly did this do though? Thank you

Comment: You were missing a file that allowed you to use jquery

Answer (score 1):

You do not include the jQuery library in the HTML you posted.

Hit F12, I am sure it says `$ is undefined` in the console.

Comment: Correct, it does say 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined', what does this mean?

Comment: Means you did not add the library that defines `$`!